# How to get the number of open file descriptors in docker

Tags: linux, docker

I am writing an application that collects docker resources data. There is a metric on DataDog's docker integration page for the number of open file descriptors as shown below in the attached image. How can I get the number of open file descriptors in docker or in general all the statistic related. If you think I am understanding this metric wrong kindly let me know what this metric is about, and what information is Datadog trying to collect ("Shown as file" meaning in the image below)?

[https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/docker/data_collected/#:~:text=docker.container.open_fds,Shown%20as%20file](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/docker/data_collected/#:%7E:text=docker.container.open_fds,Shown%20as%20file)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The datadog agent is open source so you can simply [peek inside](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/blob/38836cc7fdd422668f859f32a8faa66f5ee20d23/pkg/util/containers/metrics/system/collector_linux.go#L99-L117).

It simply maps the container ID to a linux Cgroup, then counts the number of open file descriptors for the process by counting the files in `/proc/$PID/fds`.

```
func (c *systemCollector) GetContainerOpenFilesCount(containerNS, containerID string, cacheValidity time.Duration) (*uint64, error) {
    cg, err := c.getCgroup(containerID, cacheValidity)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Get PIDs
    pids, err := cg.GetPIDs(cacheValidity)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to get PIDs for cgroup id: %s. Unable to get count of open files", cg.Identifier())
    }

    ofCount, allFailed := systemutils.CountProcessesFileDescriptors(c.procPath, pids)
    if allFailed {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to read any PID open FDs for cgroup id: %s. Unable to get count of open files", cg.Identifier())
    }

    return &ofCount, nil
}
```